# Compare Two non related entity collection in Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to compare two non related entities by using linq.

e.g -

**Entity A**

```
Id         Name            
1          A              
2          B               
3          C
4          D
```

**Entity B**

```
Id         Name

1          B

2          C
```

Result I should get

```
A, D
```

From the above two collection I want to compare Entity B with Entity A by using the Name property and find out the records which are not available in Entity B.

Any help will be appreciated with some sample code.

Regards

Comment: The downvote and close vote for: I (mildly) understand your problem, but I don't understand _what you are asking_.

Comment: @gunr2171 how about editing the answer? Or asking him to be more specific? But, really, we're all clear what he's trying to achieve even if his answer is not the most eloquent one, aren't we? All I'm saying is...it's a bit harsh...

Comment: @Leo, If I have to say "what have you tried?", I vote to close. If you don't show any research, I down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Except` extension method of LINQ. Quote from [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

> Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

#### Sample Code

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] b = { 4,5,6,7 };

var c = a.Except(b);
```

#### Result

1,2,3

#### Note

Because you are working with a custom object (a class) you will need to implement an equality comparer that compares items by the `Name` property. Example of custom equality comparer...

```
public class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<CustomObject>
{
    public bool Equals(CustomObject x, CustomObject y)
    {
        return x.Name.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CustomObject obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can use this custom equality comparer in an overload of the `Except` extension method, assumming `a` and `b` are of type `CustomObject`...

```
var c = a.Except(b, new CustomComparer());
```

The advantage is re-usability, especially if you are spreading this call to `Except` all over your project. Then,if  you need to change your entity(custom object) you only have make changes in the custom equality comparer

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = entityAs.Where(a => !entityBs.Any(b => b.Name == a.Name)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class
    class MyClass
    {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    }

Create List1

```
List<MyCLass> li1 = new List<MyCLass>();

MyCLass o1 = new MyClass();
o1.Id = 1;
o1.Name = "A";
li1.Add(o1);

o1 = new 
o1.Id = 2;
o1.Name = "B";
li1.Add(o1);

o1 = new new MyClass();
o1.Id = 3;
o1.Name = "C";
li1.Add(o1);

o1 = new new MyClass();
o1.Id = 4;
o1.Name = "D";
li1.Add(o1);
```

Create List2

```
List<MyCLass> li2 = new List<MyCLass>();
o1 = new new MyClass();
o1.Id = 1;
o1.Name = "B";
li2.Add(o1);

o1 = new new MyClass();
o1.Id = 2;
o1.Name = "C";
li2.Add(o1);

o1 = new new MyClass();
o1.Id = 3;
o1.Name = "D";
li2.Add(o1);
```

Select only Selected items which you want to compare from List1

```
List<string> SelectedName = li1.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

FinalList1 only Get those Item which are in List2

```
var FinalList = li2.Where(w => SelectedName.Contains(w.Name)).ToList();
```

/// or

FinalList2 only Get those Item which are not in List2

```
var FinalList2 = li2.Where(w => !SelectedName.Contains(w.Name)).ToList();
```